# Linux : python : clear input buffer before raw_input()

Tags: python, linux, buffer

I have looked at a few thread about this, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.
I am running linux and when I use raw_input(), with a pause between each, it will take the data that I have pressed before, here is an example :

```
 import time
 a = raw_input("first input")
 b = raw_input("second input")
 time.sleep(5)
 #flush junk?
 a = raw_input("third input")
 b = raw_input("fourth input")
```

if I press any keys followed by the enter during the 5 seconds, the two other raw input will take the input. I would like to be able to flush the data and let the user be prompted.

thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For unix you can use [termios.tcflush](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#termios.tcflush)

```
from termios import tcflush, TCIFLUSH
import time,sys

a = raw_input("first input ")
b = raw_input("second input ")

time.sleep(5)
tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIFLUSH)

a = raw_input("third input ")
b = raw_input("fourth input ")

~$ python foo.py 
first input 1
second input 2
33
33
third input 3
fourth input 4
```

**termios.tcflush(fd, queue)**

*Discard queued data on file descriptor fd. The queue selector specifies which queue: TCIFLUSH for the input queue, TCOFLUSH for the output queue, or TCIOFLUSH for both queues.*

Comment: I had a similar problem using the keyboard library and I've been struggling so much to find a solution. This still works 8 years later with Python 3.9, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use keypress getch class of tty (linux) and msvcrt (windows) and use sys.stdout.flush() function to flush the buffer

Comment: tty doesn't appear to have this class on python2.7. I'm on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: for tty it is termios class.