# Disabling input while printing with sys.stdout.write

Tags: python-3.x, input, sys

As the title says, is there any way to disable user input while printing with `sys.stdout.write`?

-

For instance if I was using this function to print out a string slowly:

```
import time
import sys


def printSlowly(text, delay):
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(delay)
```

How could I stop the user from typing anything while the function is printing things?

Note that this would be for a Linux Ubuntu terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Involved a combination of disabling echoing and flushing input.

```
# from https://gist.github.com/kgriffs/5726314
def enable_echo(enable):
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    if enable:
        new[3] |= termios.ECHO
    else:
        new[3] &= ~termios.ECHO

    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, new)

# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555070/linux-python-clear-input-buffer-before-raw-input
def flushInput():
    termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIFLUSH)
```