# Prevent reading of previous / prior user keyboard input from sys.stdin, that works with Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, command-prompt

Say you want to ask the user something from the terminal at the end of your program.
However, during the program run, the user pressed the enter key.

```
import sys
import time
print("Hit enter now to see this 'problem'")
time.sleep(1)
# Hit enter now while the program sleeps!
a=input("Do you want to delete something that is really bad to delete? [Y|n]")
if a.lower()!="n":
    print("\nNO! YOU DELETED IT!")
```

Of course, it's stupid to delete stuff with default response, and I don't do that. However, It's annoying that I, the user, sometimes hit enter and the default is what goes.

I'm *actually* using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) to read the input. So I'd want a preventative command before click executes;

```
import sys
import click
import time
print("Hit enter now to see this 'problem'")
time.sleep(1)
# Hit enter now while the program sleeps!
# Clear stdin here somehow.
sys.stdin.flush() # <- doesn't work though 
a=input("Do you want to delete something that is really bad to delete? [Y|n]")
if a.lower()!="n":
    print("\nNO! YOU DELETED IT!")
```

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 and Mac OS).

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555070/linux-python-clear-input-buffer-before-raw-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed [`termios.tcflush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#termios.tcflush) and `termios.TCIFLUSH` which does exactly what is asked:

```
import sys
from termios import tcflush, TCIFLUSH
import click
import time
print("Hit enter now to see this 'problem'")
time.sleep(1)# Hit enter while it sleeps!
tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIFLUSH)
# Discards queued data on file descriptor 'stdin'.
# TCIFLUSH specifies that it's only the input queue.
# Use TCIOFLUSH if you also want to discard output queue.

a=input("Do you want to delete something that is really bad to delete? [Y|n]")
if a.lower()!="n":
    print("\nNO! YOU DELETED IT!")
else:
    print("Phew. It's not deleted!")
```